# How can I avoid the NixOS startup error "an error occurred in stage 1 of the boot process"?

Tags: nixos

Whenever I start up my system, I get this error, "an error occurred in stage 1 of the boot process." which then prompts me to choose whether to reboot or to press `*` to continue anyway. I can press `*` and everything seems to function normally thereafter, but I'd like not to have to see this error message each time.

What could be happening here, and how do I fix this?

I thought it might be an issue with mounting drives, so I went and did a `nixos-generate-config` to regenerate the hardware config, but no dice.

[My configuration.nix and other nix files are here.](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/dotfiles/tree/master/dotfiles).

Comment: I recommend adding your sanitized `configuration.nix` to your question.

Comment: I just added a link to those files.